# How to create indoor navigation app for mall in Unity without using beacons or sensors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I have to develop a navigation app for indoor place, without using beacons or sensors, and I have to include voice command to it. 
So how could I include a map in it, so that it can show path, and navigation in it, from the user location up to the final destination in AR camera.

Comment: You are asking for so much knowledge in a single question. I don't understand what you mean navigation app indoor place, can you be more specific?

Comment: I have looked into this for a while.You can watch this youtube video from Mathew Hallberg .Once you start doing this you can customise it your way ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOMysKbDNxk&list=PLAtU-zZchkQO98jwbkLy-4ZqWozvX7QqB&index=4&t=0s